# Removing JButton Border and Fitting ImageButton inside

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a grid layout on which I have added 100 Jbuttons.Now I require to have the buttons without any margin or gap among them.What I tried is here :

```
private void initializeBoard() {
    container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
    dataPanel = new JPanel();

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<BOARD_SIZE;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<BOARD_SIZE;j++){
            squares[i][j] = new JButton(String.valueOf(numbers[index]));
            squares[i][j].addActionListener(this);

            squares[i][j].setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
            squares[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            squares[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);
            squares[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            squares[i][j].setFocusPainted(true);
            squares[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/board/"+numbers[index++]+".jpg"));

            boardPanel.add(squares[i][j]);
        }
    }
    boardPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    container.add(boardPanel);
    container.add(dataPanel);
}
```

But the result is like this.I still get vertical gaps among the buttons.
[image: Current Result]

I need to eliminate this gaps so that I get no gaps among the buttons and get the buttons to represent the whole board.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Got it.The images I was using was not wide enough to fill those areas.Thanks.

Comment: You're most likely setting size somewhere and not allowing the container that holds the JButton grid to go to its preferred size.

Comment: I have added the full class in the bottom of my question.Can you please check and confirm where I did wrong?

Comment: Get rid of all setSize and call `pack()` on your main JFrame after adding all components and see what happens.

Comment: got it the image I was using was not wide enough.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.The images I was using was not wide enough to fill those areas.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use setVgap(0), setHgap(0) to set the Vertical and Horizontal gap to zero.

Cheers!

Comment: JButton does not have setVgap or setVerticalGap method.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @sdewan64: the GridLayout has these properties, but they should **already be zero by default**.